# How to unset id attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

`$().attr('id',''`) still leaves `id = ""` snippet,

how to completely remove it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the [`removeAttr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeAttr) method.

```
$('selector').removeAttr('id')
```

Comment: love SO! Thanks.. helped great in a different context!